# The process cannot access the file 'pdf' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, process

This is part of my code:

```
foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("~/_Files/Upload/" + User.Identity.Name + "/"), "RS_*.*"))
{
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(str).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ReportingServiceImages VALUES (@ReportingServiceID, @img)";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportingServiceID", ID);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", ms.GetBuffer());
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ms.Close();
   cmd.Dispose();
   File.Delete(str);
}
```

When I try to delete `str` this IO Exeption throw:

> The process cannot access the file 'pdf' because it is being used by another process.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(str)` creates an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which needs to be disposed

```
foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("~/_Files/Upload/" + User.Identity.Name + "/"), "RS_*.*"))
{
   using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   using(Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(str))
   {
      img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      cmd.Parameters.Clear();
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ReportingServiceImages VALUES (@ReportingServiceID, @img)";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportingServiceID", ID);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", ms.GetBuffer());
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cmd.Dispose();
   }
   File.Delete(str);
}
```

If `cmd` is not actually used outside of this method, I would wrap it in a `using` statement as well.  I dont see the definition in your example, so its unclear what else it might be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Thesse type of errors can error, when the file that you are trying to access is not closed properly in the other parts of the code.

Please ensure , that the `file is closed properly` before you are trying to acess it

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

When you use disposable objects like database connections, files etc, try to use the following

```
using(var file = new ...)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

This way, when you will complete all the tasks associated with the file, database connection etc,, the corresponding object will be disposed and subsequently in other places you can create another object for accessing again your file. The reason why that happens in case of a file is pretty clear. Suppose that you have opened a file, if you don't save whatever you want there and then release it, you cannot create another object that open this file. There would turn up many inconsistencies, if that were possible.